# Crontab + Pipenv

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cron, pipenv, ubuntu-20.04

I'll be brief.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I have to add a crontab task that runs a python script with pipenv run. This script runs SELENIUM CHROMEDRIVER.

I have already tried

`0 9 * * 1-5 @user . cd /home/... ; pipenv run python file.py > /home/.../output.log`

But it does not start the script. And I need to run with pipenv, because my python global environment does not have all the libs needed to run the file.

Does someone knows how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved

The problem is that I had to run SELENIUM CHROMEDRIVER and it can't be shown by a remote console in its default configs. So I Had to add an extra line in the code:
`exports DISPLAY=:0` to run display in the server and `nohup` to not link the file operation to the shell.

`m h dom mon dow cd /home/local_of_file/ ; exports DISPLAY=:0 ; nohup pipenv run python file.py > output.log`